# Netty framework - multiple ports listening

Tags: java, streaming, netty, nio, ports

I have the following problem. I have modified this example for myself : 
[Webcam Capture Live Streaming Example](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-live-streaming)

At the moment, the communication looks like client1 sends the image to the server, and the image from the server is sent to client2. There is no problem if I work with one camera. Problems start if I stream from two different cameras. I would like client1 to send the image to the server on a specific port and only on that port the server sends the image to the client.2 At the moment it is (I don't know why) the case that what the server gets, e.g. on port 2000 it sends to all ports, not only port 2000. Can you help me?

Some code from server:

```
@Override
public void start(SocketAddress streamAddress) {
    logger.info("server started:{}", streamAddress);
    Channel channel = serverBootstrap.bind(streamAddress);
    channelGroup.add(channel);
}
```

.

```
    this.serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
    this.serverBootstrap.setFactory(new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
    this.serverBootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new StreamServerChannelPipelineFactory(new StreamServerListenerIMPL(), streamFrameListener));
```

.

```
public static void send(BufferedImage image) throws Exception {
    Object msg = h264StreamEncoder.encode(image);
    channelGroup.write(msg);
}
```

Code from client1 :

```
public static void init(String host, int port) {
    Webcam webcam = Webcam.getWebcams().get(0);

    Dimension sizeVideo = WebcamResolution.QVGA.getSize();
    webcam.setViewSize(sizeVideo);

    StreamAtmAgent atmAgent = new StreamAtmAgent(webcam, sizeVideo);
    atmAgent.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
}
```

.
Code from client2 :

```
public static void init(String host, int port, ImageListener il) {
    displayWindow.setVisible(true);
    logger.info("Ustawione wymiary :{}", dimension);
    StreamClientAgent clientAgent = new StreamClientAgent(il, dimension);
    clientAgent.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
}
```

Can you help me? If you need more code, tell me.

P.S When I do something like this in start server:

```
init("localhost",2000)
init("localhost",2001)
```

And I connect my client1 to server with port 2000 and I connect client2 to port 2001. I still see image from port 2000.

Comment: Show us where do you define the channel group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your channelGroup is shared between all threads for all clients? In that SET you add all channels - no matters which port they are listening to:

```
 Channel channel = serverBootstrap.bind(streamAddress);
 channelGroup.add(channel); //I guess all channels are added here
```

Ans from netty documentation [here](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html#write-java.lang.Object-) `write` method does:

> Writes the specified message to all Channels in this group. If the
>   specified message is an instance of ByteBuf, it is automatically
>   duplicated to avoid a race condition. The same is true for
>   ByteBufHolder. Please note that this operation is asynchronous as
>   Channel.write(Object) is.

So you basically here  `channelGroup.write(msg);`  you send the same message(image) to all channels. You would need to separate the channel for port 2000 from the one on port 2001. I don't think you even need a channelGroup. Just send the image for port 2000 to the channel created for port 2000.

Comment: How can I do it? My assumption is that one client1 sends the image to the server on a specific port and the server sends the image to any number of clients2 on this port. There will be several such connections with different ports.

Comment: Post the code of your channelGroup? You need to have a channelGroup of clients on the specific port, and not channelGroup of channels(which are basically servers)

Comment: I don't think you need a channelGroup at all to be honest :) You just need to send the image received from the specific camera to the specific channel  and currently you send it to all channels through the group

Comment: My channelGroup is default. It means : protected static final ChannelGroup channelGroup = new DefaultChannelGroup();

Comment: That's what I mean - you get one big collection of channels and you add all channels (for all ports) to that channel group. When you write to the group - it writes the same message to all channels. Try writing directly to the channel you need

Comment: So, how I can do this? I must have a List of ChannelGroup at first. And ?

Comment: You don't need a group. Youbcan write to thw channel.  I told you the problem playbaroubd withnit for a bit and it will work 

Comment: I understand you, but I have several different clients1 and several different clients2. How do I know to which client2 what image should I send?

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance - I hope you did it in the end ;)